# Bootstrap component not showing properly in react project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I make a react project with yarn. I install bootstrap with `yarn add bootstrap`. After that I import `'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` and copy paste bootstrap navbar to my code. But when started the display looks messy.

**The App.js code**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**The result**
[image]

**Edit:**

I was try with the react bootstrap instead of regular bootstrap but the result still same
[image]

**My App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar,Nav,NavDropdown,Form,FormControl,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Form inline>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction instead of plain bootstrap.
It has the functionality of the components along the styles.

Would save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I was try with react-bootstrap but the result is same, look at my update. Maybe the problem is in my node_modules

Comment: Did you try to remove the node_modules directory and run npm i again?

You could try to add 100% with to the parent div.

Comment: i was delete the node modules and install it again, but nothing changes